# What is the best way to remap a Hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, remap

Is there a simple way of remapping a hash in ruby the following way:

from:

```
{:name => "foo", :value => "bar"}
```

to:

```
{"foo" => "bar"}
```

Preferably in a way that makes it simple to do this operation while iterating over an array of this type of hashes:

from:

```
[{:name => "foo", :value => "bar"}, {:name => "foo2", :value => "bar2"}]
```

to:

```
{"foo" => "bar", "foo2" => "bar2"}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
arr = [ {:name=>"foo", :value=>"bar"}, {:name=>"foo2", :value=>"bar2"}]

result = {}
arr.each{|x| result[x[:name]] = x[:value]}

# result is now {"foo2"=>"bar2", "foo"=>"bar"}
```

Comment: Yes, this is almost what I did also, but I used x.values[0] and x.values[1] instead of x[:name] and x[:value], in case I don't know the keys in advance. 

I was fishing for an even simpler way to do this, but there might not be one...

Comment: Hash values are out of order so you can't do x.values[0] and x.values[1]

Comment: +1 to Vanson.. you can see that the result contents are already out of order since its a Hash.

Answer (score 3):

A modified version of Vanson Samuel's code does the intended. 
It's a one-liner, but quite a long one.

```
arr = [{:name=>"foo", :value=>"bar"}, {:name=>"foo2", :value=>"bar2"}]

arr.inject({}){|r,item| r.merge({item['name'] => item['value']})}

# result {"foo" => "bar", "foo2" => "bar2"}
```

I wouldn't say that it's prettier than Gishu's version, though.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, if you have a hash of the form {:name => "foo", :value => "bar"}, you're usually better off with using a tuple of ["foo", "bar"].

```
arr = [["foo", "bar"], ["foo2", "bar2"]]
arr.inject({}) { |accu, (key, value)| accu[key] = value; accu }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but the neatest way to achieve this is to map the array of hashes to an array of tuples, then use Hash[] to build a hash from that, as follows:

```
arr = [{:name => "foo", :value => "bar"}, {:name => "foo2", :value => "bar2"}]
Hash[ array.map { |item| [ item[:name], item[:value] ] } ]

# => {"foo"=>"bar", "foo2"=>"bar2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but:

```
[{ name: "foo", value: "bar" },{name: "foo2", value: "bar2"}].map{ |k| k.values }.to_h
```